# What are the names in this Status Animarum from Slovenia?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, vital-records, slovenia, austria-hungary

I have a [Status Animarum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parish_family_book) for Mali Cirnik 12 in the Šentrupert parish records stored at Ljubljana diocese in Austro-Hungarian Empire (present day Slovenia).

[image: Source image for Status Animarum for Mali Cirnik 12]

The third line matches the birth date of [Franc Gregorčič](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Gregor%C4%8Di%C4%8D-5) of 27 Nov 1839 and has the proper birth location of Mali Cirnik 12.  It appears Mali Cirnik was called Kleinz Zirnik, perhaps in German, during earlier time frame of this record.

I also think that perhaps the `č` is written as something like `zf` giving something like `Gregorzfizf` instead of the more modern `Gregorčič` or perhaps this is a german spelling?

But then the `r` looks more like a `m` to me.  I think the month on the first line is March and written in German as `März`, but again the `r` looks very weird.  The wife's first name might be Maria or something close to that.  The bottom person appears to be for an Ursula born 27 September 1808.

What kind of language is this written in and why does the cursive seem so unusual to my eye?

What I'd like to know is what are the names of the father on line 1, mother on line 2, siblings on lines 3-5, and other folks on lines 6-7?

What is the note written on the last line?

Also, what are the months of birth given?

Are these Slovenian or German month name abbreviations?

Note that the `1` for the first digit of the year like in 1802 on line 1 is omitted for each birth year given, in this case as just `802`.

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions within this one.  I think that you should consider splitting it into several questions.

Comment: Do you have an image of the column headings?

Comment: There are no column headings in this older version of the S.A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page is written in German, in the [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) handwriting style

```
12. Joseph Gregorzhizh  Klein=Zirnik    13. März '802
    Weib [=wife], Maria Jurglizh        8.  Dec. '805

    Sohn [=son], Franz                  27. Nov. '839
    dto. [=ditto], Martin               30. Sept. '842

    Tochter [=daughter], Maria           4. Feb. '838

    Johann, Bruder [=brother] ausgeh--?* 12. Dec. '818.
    Ursula, Schwester [=sister]          27. Sept. '808

    bloyd? dinz? **
```

German doesn't use zh - German names would have used ch or sch
Dropping the first digit of the year is not unusual in older records.

*abbreviation, tbd full word [preliminary translation: a verb in past tense + out or away] 
** sloppily written, tbd correct transcription, perhaps not German

Comment: Do you think Weiß means wife?

Comment: Good catch - 1 letter mis-transcribed