# What is German translation of this Marriage record written in Kurrent?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, marriage-records, austria-hungary, kurrent

I have an photo of a computer showing a scan of a marriage register for the household shown in [this answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/13670/2586) which is also written in German using [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) style of cursive:

[image]

I'd like to know what the first and second line's marriage information is.

For the first marriage, I see it is 2nd day of perhaps February in 1837.  Bride is Marija Gregorzhizh, age 36, who appears to be sister to groom on second line.  Groom is Anton Ob...., age 31, lives in Klein Zirnik 14 (Slovenian is Mali Cirnik 14).

For the second marriage, I see it is 5th day of some month in 1837, perhaps the prior line is for month of February.  Groom lives in Klein Zirnik house number 12.  Groom's name is Joseph Gregorzhizh, age 35, which translates to Slovenian name Joseph Gregorčič.  Bride is Maria Jurglizh, age 31, who lives in Preflef jc 2 (not sure what town that is, but house number is 2).

All four getting married are Catholic faith.

In particular, I'm very interested in the names of the parent's of each bride and groom and the names of the witnesses of each marriage.  I think the Gregorčič parents might be Anton Gregorčič and wife Ursula, however, the document looks more like Joseph and Maria, so maybe Joseph and Anton are brothers or cousins?

A later generation marriage transcription, that helps decoding the column headings, is shown in this image with both Slovenian and Latin words:

[image]

Comment: Since this is a very recent document, I hope you exchanged the names in the form, and I strongly suggest that you cover up that offical's signature and the stamp. Please don't publish unique signatures, dates and real persons' names on the web, it just invites abuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Header in Gothic typeface & German language; some words use archaic spelling:

```
[Seite] 114, Trauungs=Buch
Jahr Monath und Tag der Trauung.
Bräutigam
-Wohnort
-Haus Nro.
-Taufnahme [sic], Familien=Nahme, Stand.
-Religion - Katholisch / Akatholisch
-Altersjahre
-Ledig / Wittwer
Braut
-Wohnort
-Haus Nro.
-Taufnahme [sic], Familien=Nahme, Stand.
-Religion - Katholisch / Akatholisch
-Altersjahre
-Ledig / Wittwe
Aeltern des Bräutigams.
-Taufnahme, Familiennahme und Stand des Vaters 
-Tauf= und Familiennahme und Stand der Mutter 
Aeltern der Braut
-Taufnahme, Familiennahme und Stand des Vaters 
-Tauf= und Familiennahme und Stand der Mutter 
Beystände
-Tauf= und Familien= nahme
-Stand
Urkunden, wodurch allenfalls vorgekommene Anstände gehoben wurden.
Unterschrift des trauenden Priesters.
```

---

Header translation:

```
[Page] 114, Wedding book
Year Month and day of the wedding ceremony.
Groom
-place of residence, house number
-given name, surname and status
-religion - Catholic or non-catholic
-age in years
-single or widower
Bride
-place of residence, house number
-given name, surname and status
-religion - Catholic or non-catholic
-age in years
-single or widow
Parents of the groom.
-given name, surname and father's status
-given name, surname and mother's status
Parents of the bride
-given name, surname and father's status
-given name, surname and mother's status
Witnesses
-given name and surname, status
Documents, including how any interfering circumstances were lifted.
Signature of the officiating priest.
```

---

1st entry on page, transcript:

```
[getraut (married)] am 2ten Februar 1837

[Bräutigam (Groom)]
Klein Zirnik, 14
Anton Obacha, 1/3 Hübler
1 [katholisch] -
31 [Jahre]
1 [ledig] -

[Braut (Bride)]
Klein Zirnik, 12
Maria Gregorzhizh, Halbh. Tochter
1 [katholisch] -
36 [Jahre]
1 [ledig] 1 [durchgestrichen, nicht Wittwe]

[Eltern des Bräutigams (his parents)]
Mathia Obacha, 1/3 Hübler
Agnes Renko?

[Eltern der Bräut (her parents]
Johann Gregorzhizh, 1/2 Hübler
Maria Kunnet?

[Zeugen (witnesses)]
Mathia Metulko, Halbhübler
Franz Umat?, 1/3 Hübler

[Urkunden (documentation)]
durch bezirks- oberg?keitliche Bewilligung

[Priester (officiant)]
Bartholme Pezhnik?, Pop
```

---

2nd entry on page, transcript:

```
[getraut (married)] am 5ten Februar

[Bräutigam (groom)]
Klein Zirnik, 12
Joseph Gregorzhizh, Halbhübler
1 [katholisch] -
35 [Jahre]
- 1 [Wittwer]

[Braut (bride)]
Prelesje, 2
Maria Jurglizh, Hüblerstochter
1 [katholisch] -
31 [Jahre]
1 [ledig] -

[Eltern des Bräutigams (his parents)]
Johann Gregorzhizh, Halbhübl.
Maria Kennet?

[Eltern der Bräut (her parents)]
Franz Jurglizh, Ganzhübler
Maria Maizen?

[Zeugen (witnesses)]
Mathia Neklappa?, Ganzh.
Anton Gregorzhizh, Ganzhübler

[Urkunden (documentation)]
durch bezirks- oberg?keitliche Bewilligung

[Priester (officiant)]
Bartholme Pezhnik?, Pop
```

Notes
1) 1837 implied after 1st entry, as entries chronological
2) Pop = Father (title)
3) Hübler (abbreviated h.) (Ganzhübler, 1/2 or Halb-, 1/3 ...) - a cottager, with distinctions on how large a property he had: a full or whole parcel, one-half or one-third. Derived from Hube or Hufe, a measure of area.
4) documentation column references an official license or permission

Surnames are tough to transcribe when there are few examples of a particular name.