# What is this first name for Gregorčič witness to marriage?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, marriage-records, austria, german-language

I have a marriage record from 1837 written in German with a groom's witness with surname Gregorčič (written Gregorzhizh in German).  It appears close to `Anton` but that doesn't quite work to my eye, so I'd like to decipher what the name is, underlined in red:

[image]

Could it be Johann (name of both father and brother of groom)?

Comment: It is "Anton", as already transcribed in the answer to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/what-is-german-translation-of-this-marriage-record-written-in-kurrent The extra flourishes in the A are almost vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: @bgwiehle Sounds like the answer, can you convert to an answer?

Comment: Because this question really is a subset of the earlier question, I wondered if it was going to be labelled a duplicate or withdrawn, thus my comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @bgwiehle Ok, then I suggest updating the answer there to include the bit about extra flourishes in the A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It is "Anton", as already transcribed in a [previous answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/what-is-german-translation-of-this-marriage-record-written-in-kurrent). The extra flourishes in the A are almost vertical instead of horizontal.