# Did the spelling of this surname change or is it misread?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, vital-records, austria

I have several examples of this same surname over time as shared in [this answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/13679/2586) for a marriage record.

Oldest example in Kurrent handwriting (around 1800):
[image]

Groom of the marriage in 1837:

[image]

Father of groom of the marriage in 1837:

[image]

Next oldest around mid 1800s:

[image]

Around 1873:

[image]

And these three from around 1876:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The modern spellings appear to clearly be Obaha, so are the earlier ones misread, stylistic variations, or what?

Comment: You're imposing 20th/21st century ideas of standardized spelling on an era where those standards didn't exist.  Consider that in most original records, people have dictated their names to a clerk who wrote the record down, and even if they were literate themselves, they may not have seen their own entries in register books if there wasn't a requirement for them to sign the register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a change from Obacha to Obaha. Could be a spelling change between languages (similar to zh to č); could be a pronunciation change over time, reflected in the spelling; could be due to different native language of the record-keepers (who recorded names as they heard them, using the spelling conventions they were familiar with).

[image]